# Installing CUDA 5.0 RC samples

Tags: cuda, installation

I tried to install the full CUDA 5.0 package but I got the following error:

```
Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Not Selected
Samples:  Installation Failed. Missing required libraries.
```

So, in the /tmp/cuda_install_2340.log I've got:

```
Missing required library libglut.so
```

But I have installed it before, because I do:

```
facundo@gpgpu:~$ locate libglut
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0
```

So, What is the problem? I am on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: do you get any different results if you put those libglut libraries in /usr/lib or /usr/lib64?  Is /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu on your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: The following fix it: "sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so /usr/lib/libglut.so " Thank you!

Comment: @facunvd can you post your solution as an answer and accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Same distribution, same problem.The symbolic link fixed it for me too.  Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, I fixed it by the following:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so /usr/lib/libglut.so
```

So the problem was ubuntu are installing libglut library in a different path for x64 architectures, so it can be fixed making a symbolic link to /usr/lib/.

Comment: Running 32-bit Ubuntu, `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

On `CentOS 5.6 x64` , `Kernel: 2.6.18-308.24.1.el5`

```
1. yum install freeglut

2. ln -s /usr/lib/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so
```

then i also install `CUDA 5.0` Sample successfully.

Thanks this post.

Comment: Solved my problem on 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 x64 actually creates a /usr/lib/glut.so -- it just points to libglut.so.3 not /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so

```
rm /usr/lib/libglut.so;
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so /usr/lib/libglut.so
```