# Installing cuda 5 samples in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, installation

I'm trying to install cuda 5 samples:

```
Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Not Selected
Samples:  Installation Failed. Missing required libraries.
```

But I got this error:

```
Missing required library libglut.so
```

But:

```
frederico@zeus:~/Downloads$ sudo find / -name libglut.so*
/usr/lib/libglut.so
/usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libglut.so
```

Where nvidia installer is looking for? maybe /usr/lib64? There is no /usr/lib64 on Ubuntu 12.10:

```
frederico@zeus:~/Downloads$ ls /usr
bin  games  include  lib  lib32  local  sbin  share  src

frederico@zeus:~/Downloads$ uname -a
Linux zeus 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing CUDA 5.0 RC samples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883128/installing-cuda-5-0-rc-samples)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am also running Ubuntu 12.10 and I found this library in folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` after installing **freeglut3** package.

I also make a softlink and I have been able to install **CUDA 5.0** examples:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so
```

I have not checked if the samples can be compiled yet.

Comment: You're welcome, I have compiled many samples. However, I have not been able to compile whole set. I think that it could be because of some particular libraries that are used in samples.

Comment: have you ever used nsight to debug some cuda code? I just posted a question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991271/cuda-gdb-not-working-in-nsight-on-linux

Comment: @rpardo I had also problems but only with the simpleMPI one, which I just deleted.

Comment: Installing freeglut and softlinking libglut.so worked on centos 6 too.

Comment: Running 32-bit Ubuntu, `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so` worked for me

Comment: Additionally, I was able to get through the installer by changing my /usr/bin/gcc and /usr/bin/g++ symlinks from gcc-4.7 to gcc-4.6.

Answer (score 4):

I got CUDA-5.0 to work very fine on Ubuntu 12.10. It built the samples. I was also able to compile OpenCV-2.4.4 with Cuda support, than ffmpeg with libopencv support speeding the editing and encoding of Videos up to 8x.

I've done this:

1. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-26 freeglut3-dev mpich-dev gcc-4.6 g++-4.6`
2. Don't install the nvidia-driver from the ubuntu repository!, download the latest Driver from nvidia.com and do: `chmod +x (Downloadpath)/*run`  than `sudo lightdm stop`  than cd (Downloadpath) than `sudo ./NV*run` than `sudo restart`
3. download the ubuntu-11X-version of cuda-5.0 from nvidia.com and install it (sudo ./*run) **without the offered dev-driver**, answer the question about install-Path with " /opt/cuda-5.0
4. the default version of gcc in ubuntu 12.10 (gcc-4.7) conflicts with the Cuda-Code. so let cuda use the perv. gcc-version: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 /opt/cuda-5.0/bin/gcc`
5. let ldconf know about the cuda-libs: `echo '/opt/cuda-5.0/lib64' > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia-cuda.conf && echo '/opt/cuda-5.0/lib' >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia-cuda.conf` than do: `sudo ldconfig`
6. Many programs search for the (nvidia)-OpenCL-Include-Files in /usr/include. **But** they are not there, so link to them:   `sudo ln -s /opt/cuda-5.0/include/CL /usr/include/CL` **and** `sudo ln -s /opt/cuda-5.0/include/CL /usr/include/OpenCL`
7. Cuda can build the sample now. **But** if you want to compile Program-Sourcecode e.g. OpenCV you need to change **temorarily** the symbolic links in order to point at gcc-4.6 and g++-4.6: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/bin/gcc` - `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.6 /usr/bin/g++` - `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.6 /usr/bin/c++`
8. In order to avoid version-conflicts try to compile all other dependent Packages with those symlinks (e.g. OpenCV+ffmpeg+frei0r-plugins)

   1. After compiling: Don't forget to correct the gcc and g++ symlinks to point at Version 4.7!!

Comment: didn't try it but awesome contribution!

Answer (score 2):

CUDA 5 is not yet supported on Ubuntu 12.
For reference see [CUDA 5.0 Toolkit Release Notes And Errata](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt)

```
**  Distributions Currently Supported  

    Distribution       32 64  Kernel                 GCC         GLIBC        
    -----------------  -- --  ---------------------  ----------  -------------
    Fedora 16          X  X   3.1.0-7.fc16           4.6.2       2.14.90      
    ICC Compiler 12.1     X                                                   
    OpenSUSE 12.1         X   3.1.0-1.2-desktop      4.6.2       2.14.1       
    Red Hat RHEL 6.x      X   2.6.32-131.0.15.el6    4.4.5       2.12         
    Red Hat RHEL 5.5+     X   2.6.18-238.el5         4.1.2       2.5          
    SUSE SLES 11 SP2      X   3.0.13-0.27-pae        4.3.4       2.11.3       
    SUSE SLES 11.1     X  X   2.6.32.12-0.7-pae      4.3.4       2.11.1       
    Ubuntu 11.10       X  X   3.0.0-19-generic-pae   4.6.1       2.13         
    Ubuntu 10.04       X  X   2.6.35-23-generic      4.4.5       2.12.1
```

Comment: I could not install the samples but could compile my projects, so I'm ok. Thank you!

Comment: [Indeed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203050/does-cuda-work-on-quantal-quetzal-12-10)...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to create a softlink from lib64 to lib using:

```
ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64
```

Comment: The selection between 32 and 64 bit libraries is not done like that anymore. Instead there are two sub-directories under /usr/lib/... one of which is mentioned in an earlier answer: x86_64-linux-gnu