# cuda-gdb not working in nsight on linux

Tags: linux, cuda, nsight, cuda-gdb, optimus

I installed cuda 5 in my Ubuntu 12.10 and it is working well, I can compile and debug through cuda-gdb in terminal as well. I'm trying to use nsight, it compiles and executes my code with no issues, but when I try to debug I got the following error

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-gdb-set cuda api_failures ignore
Error message from debugger back end:
Undefined set cuda command: "api_failures ignore".  Try "help set cuda".
Undefined set cuda command: "api_failures ignore".  Try "help set cuda".
```

I'm using ubuntu 12.10 64 bits and launching cuda executables and nsight with optirun (bumblebee) because I have a GTX 675M (optimus). I installed cuda-gdb throught apt-get, I got version 4.2:

```
frederico@zeus:~/Dropbox/coisas/projetos/delta_cuda$ cuda-gdb --version
NVIDIA (R) CUDA Debugger
4.2 release
Portions Copyright (C) 2007-2012 NVIDIA Corporation
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
```

I think this is not a problem since I can use it alone (without nsight). I changed nsight to launch cuda-gdb with optirun as well, keep receiving the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the version of cuda-gdb, I had to use cuda-gdb version 5. It comes with the toolkit version 5, just did a symbolic lick to /usr/bin and it's working.

Comment: You got this message because Nsight tried to run one of the newer cuda-gdb commands that was only introduced in CUDA 5.0.

Comment: Your solution works but is difficult to set up on a multi-user system where you're not administrator. Most of the times, sysadmins will be reluctant to add links to `/opt` in `/usr/bin`...

Answer (score 2):

It is ***possible* to debug CUDA programs with nsight and bumblebee**.
(nsight v.5.0.0, bumblebee 3.2.1, Debian sid)

You just have to replace the debugger command line (*CUDA GDB Executable*) in: 
*Project Explorer -> right click on your project -> select "Debug as" -> click on "Debug configurations..." -> select "Debugger" tab*

CUDA GDB Executable: `optirun --no-xorg cuda-gdb`
(another possibility is to make a small shell script like the one that follows: `/usr/bin/opti-cuda-gdb`)

```
#!/bin/bash
optirun --no-xorg /usr/bin/cuda-gdb $*
```

This way optirun does not start a virtual screen for gdb, the GPU is not accepting graphics and debug is possible.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create this link.

You can select the `cuda-gdb` executable used by nsight in the *Run/Debug Configurations...* Menu.
In this menu, click on your application under *C/C++ Application*, then choose the *Debugger* tab where you can browse your filesystem and set the path to the cuda-gdb-5.0 executable.

Comment: That will work. However set this to all users, for me, is a bigger problem than explain the situation to the administrator

Comment: Again I don't agree. Because if every user uses cuda-gdb-5.0, then it should be installed in a default location, or the user `PATH` should be updated accordingly to the location. Still, enjoy `cuda-gdb` :)