# Errors during make of Cuda-5.0 SDK(Ubuntu 64), undefined reference to 'dlsym'

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nvidia

```
The toolkit and items 1-6 of the NVIDIA_CUDA SDK have been installed and compiled , but when it gets to '6_Advanced/cdpLUDecomposition' the following error message appears.
```

> 

```
  /usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/nvcc -m64 -Xcompiler -fopenmp -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35  -o cdpLUDecomposition dlaswp.o dgetf2.o dgetrf.o cdp_lu.o cdp_lu_main.o -L/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64 -lcublas -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt -lgomp 
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcublas.so: error: undefined reference to 'dlsym'
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcublas.so: error: undefined reference to 'dlopen'
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcublas.so: error: undefined reference to 'dlclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cdpLUDecomposition] Error 1
```

I am new to both Ubuntu and Cuda, but did try adding LD_FLAGS=-ldl before the make which was no help, and set the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the Nvidia recommendations. Also I updated all drivers and was able to get a valid result from the SDK deviceQuery Program.

Any help would be appreciated as everything else I have tried did not yet work.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: It's not a supported OS.  You can review the supported OS's in the installer [release notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#linux).  If you don't care about the cdpLUDecomposition example, you can do a `make -k` instead of a regular make, and it will build all the targets that it can.  This is a library naming or install location issue of some sort, and others have had similar problems trying to get things to work on ubuntu 12.xx like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986701/installing-cuda-5-samples-in-ubuntu-12-10).

Comment: Thank you Robert. I did see that 12.04 was not on the supported list but did not make the connection to that problem.

Comment: using make -k did work as you said, and I think that was the only example which generated errors. Hopefully full support for 12.04 will come soon.

Comment: @user582184: I had a similar problem with a new Ubuntu but not related to CUDA. What you can try is to put '-ldl' linker flag at the very end of your linker command. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-ldl` should be sufficient. Enter in the directory of the sample (`cd 6_Advanced/cdpLUDecomposition`) and check the build command with `make`. On my machine it is

/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/nvcc -m64 -Xcompiler -fopenmp -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35  -o cdpLUDecomposition dlaswp.o dgetf2.o dgetrf.o cdp_lu.o cdp_lu_main.o -L/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64 -lcublas -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt -lgomp

You can either

- Run the build command manually appending `-ldl`, or
- Fix the Makefile in the directory by appending `-ldl` to the proper LDFLAGS (line 89), which is cleaner and safer for next rebuilds

`ldd cdpLUDecomposition` then shows it is linked to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2.